# In converting to a smaller-bit floating representation, what does a negative biased exponent mean?

Tags: floating-point

I'm working on homework that asks me to convert from an 8-bit representation to a 6-bit one.

I'm reading [9-bit floating point representations using IEEE floating point format A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261647/9-bit-floating-point-representations) to help me out.

But, after adding the new bias to the unbiased exponent, I get a negative number. What does this mean? Is this underflow?

Comment: It's important to understand which scheme for exponents is being used.  Some schemes use an unsigned exponent and others use an signed one.  If an unsigned exponent is used then a "negative" exponent means that an underflow has occurred.  As Sneftel suggests, sometimes it's possible to represent a "minor" underflow with a "denormalized" number (by dropping significand bits from the right), but again that depends on the particulars of the FP representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's underflow. It's best to check for range before adding the bias, but in any case, underflow/overflow means an unrepresentable exponent. Underflow should be converted to either a denormal representation or zero as appropriate; overflow should be clamped to the maximum exponent and the mantissa set to zero, indicating infinity.