# ieee format A to format B by rounding

Tags: binary, rounding, ieee

So i have two 9 bit floating point representations based on IEEE floating point format.

Format A: 1 sign bit, k=5 exponent bits, n = 3 fraction bits, and a bias of 15

Format B: 1 sign bit, k=4 exponent bits, n = 4 fraction bits, and a bias of 7

I am suppose to convert format A to Format B and use rounding towards +infinity.
The example problem they gave is:

Format A

bits: 1 01111 001

value: -9/8

Format B

bits: 1 0111 0010

value: -9/8

I completely understand how to convert the binary to decimal form, but i am completely lost on how they converted 1 01111 001 to 1 0111 0010.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: If you understand both binary-to-decimal and decimal-to-binary, then A-to-decimal-to-B shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13261647/270986

Answer (score 1):

The Exponent bits are the main focus when switching because you need to convert using the different bias for each format. So looking at the example you were given:

FORMAT A has bias of 15 and exponent binary value of 15 (01111) so you take your binary value - bias like you would if you were trying to get the IEEE value; therefore, giving you zero. When computing the IEEE value your equation looks like this:

2^0 * 1.001. The 1.001 is 1 times your fractional bits value.

Now we convert to FORMAT B.

FORMAT B has 4 exponent bits.  So we take the exponent of your equation which is 0 and use the B bias to find what your bit string needs to be.

bit-string value - bias = exponent in equation.  This is just like finding the exponent when finding IEEE value of a bit-string.

bit-string value = 0 + bias = 0 + 7 since B bias is 7.

Therefore the bit-string value we need is that of 7: 0111

Combining what we have so far we get: 0(sign bit) , 0111(exponent bits), 001(fractional bits) == 0 0111 001.

Now we have to get a fractional bit-string of length 4 for FORMAT B. We have 001 and need to add some bit into the string at the last digit so we have something in the form 001_ where the _ represents the new bit added.  Since you want to keep precision as close to the original format as possible you make it a 0.  NEVER make it 1 because that changes your fractional bit-string up by a factor of 2, thus losing precision.

Now we combine it all together to get:  0 0111 0010 which is the examples final answer.

So when converting between different formats you need to remember two simple guidelines:

1. If you are adding bits: 3 --> 4 fractional bits, zero's are added to the end to make the bit-string the length you need.
2. If you are "deleting" bits: 4 --> 3 fractional bits, the rightmost (least significant) bit is lost.  Thus 0111 --> 011(1) where the (1) is the "deleted bit."